# associative arrays and loops

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to select employees with `employee_id` from 100 to 110, loop through `emp` table and add 10% to each `emp_salary`, then display results from the `emp` table

```
DECLARE
  vname VARCHAR(100);
  TYPE emp_table_type is TABLE OF employees.last_name%TYPE
  INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  vname_table emp_table_type;

BEGIN
  for i in 100..110
    SELECT last_name into vname from employees where employee_id = i;
  end loop;

  vname_table(1) := vname;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(vname_table(1));
End;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: this code has to select employees with employee_id = to the range nd increment their salary by 10% and then display result in the emp table..how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to select employees with employee_id from 100 to 110, loop
>   through emp table and add 10% to each emp_salary, then display results
>   from the emp table

You can do it as :

```
DECLARE
   sal           NUMBER;    
   TYPE emp_table_type IS TABLE OF employee.employee_id%TYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;    
   vname_table   emp_table_type;

BEGIN
  ---Selecting employee
   SELECT employee_id
     BULK COLLECT INTO vname_table
     FROM employee
    WHERE employee_id BETWEEN 100 AND 110;

   FOR i IN 1 .. vname_table.LAST
   LOOP
        --- Updating Salary 
         UPDATE Employee
            SET salary = salary + (salary * 0.10)
          WHERE employee_id = vname_table (i)
      RETURNING salary
           INTO sal;

     --- Displaying updated salary
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (sal);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: @GiftKamogelo It's worth noting that whilst XING has answered your question (which I'm sure is to do with learning PL/SQL), in the real world, you wouldn't use an array to do this - instead, you'd use a single update statement, e.g. `update employee set salary = salary * 1.1 where employee_id between 100 and 110;`. Always use a set-based approach where you can, since this will be more efficient than row-by-row processing.